# Excel Macro: If Column B contains 12 digits then column C equals 3?

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm trying to figure out how to write an Excel macro to populate Column C with either 3 or a 4 depending on the amount of numbers contained in Column B.

I have searched up and down for the right wording to this, but I keep coming up short.

Basically, I need the macro to look at the number of digits in Column B.  If there are 12 digits then the number is a UPC, and if there are 13 then the number is an EAN.  I then need the macro to populate Column C with a 3 for UPCs and a 4 for EANs.  This needs to be for the entire range of rows in the spreadsheet.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the length of a cell's value by using `Len()` like this `Len(Range("A1"))` for example.

Now you just need to loop through your column and look at each value.  If you look for the last used cell and loop only through that range your loop will be faster.

Here is how I would do it:

```
sub TestUPC()
  With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  Dim rRng As Range
  Set rRng = Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

  For Each cell In rRng.Cells
    If Len(Trim(cell))=12 then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 3
    ElseIf Len(Trim(cell))=13 then
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 4
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

---

An in cell equation could look like this:

```
=IF(LEN(B1)=12,3,IF(LEN(B1)=13,4," "))
```

As suggested in the comments you might want to test for spaces depending on your data:

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=12,3,IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=13,4," "))
```

Comment: I would suggest adding "trim" to remove any spaces before / after the number. Otherwise, a space character might trick you into thinking it is an EAN, when it's really a UPC: `=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=12,3,IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=13,4," "))` (A similar function is available in VBA.)

Comment: Thanks!  This worked like a charm!  I didn't use the trim feature because our inventory program exports the data.  I couldn't find any spaces.

Just in case, what would the VBA code be to test for the spaces?  I tend to prefer using the VBA macros instead of the in cell because we download a new version of this file a couple of times of day.  With the macros I can just keep them in a separate spreadsheet and open that in conjunction with this inventory file.

Thanks again for this!  I definitely appreciate the assistance from Stumptown!  =)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a dirty old loop,  try this (much faster if you have lots of rows):

```
Sub HTH()

    With Sheet1.Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
        .Formula = "=IF(LEN(TRIM(B1))=12,3,IF(LEN(TRIM(B1))=13,4,""""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Or use a user defined function, which has the advantage of changing when the data in column B is updated.

Better yet just use a formula, you don't really need VBA.

Alternative VBA Method (looping the fast way):

```
Sub HTH()
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim lCnt As Long

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        vArray = .Value

        For lCnt = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
            Select Case Len(Trim(vArray(lCnt, 1)))
            Case 12: vArray(lCnt, 1) = 3
            Case 13: vArray(lCnt, 1) = 4
            Case Else:
            End Select
        Next lCnt

        .Offset(, 1).Value = vArray
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought it was kind of funny.  I get what you're trying to say.  The cell formula code is a bit "cleaner" per se, but I guess I'm old school and like the loops.  Either way though, whatever floats your boat!

We're running this on about 2300 rows, so not a huge deal.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Your welcome, and your not the first to say that, a lot of vba developers will reach straight for a loop when they come across a problem. Its a quick fix and its the first thing that comes to mind.  But when code gets more complex and the database grows they can become a nightmare, taking advantage of excels built in functionality will see you right.  It aint an easy habit to break though I must admit. :)

Comment: You realize that your still looping but it's just behind the scenes in excel?  Also, the OP asked for a macro solution which typically means they are expecting to make other enhancements or modification to suit their additional needs.  Your solution, though it's a macro, is really a formula solution.  My answer was down voted as well without a comment.  Guess someone wasn't happy that day.

Comment: @Portland yes of course.  But there are fast ways to loop and slow ways.  Sorry, but in excel - your's is one of the slowest.  I have updated my answer if you would like to see one of the faster ways.  With regard to what you have suggested is a formula answer, I don't have a crystal ball, many times people ask for a macro because they don't realise that they don't actually need one.  I am simple trying to provide the cleanest and most efficient code possible with the info given.

Comment: @Portland FYI: [Dont get caught in the loop](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm)